# How to withdraw some amount(not ether) from smart contract using web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm trying to make a system something like 'anyone can send some amount to the register centers' and after that those center can withdraw the amount. But this amount is not ether. It can be some number or money.

So I'm able to to send some amount to this register center but I'm facing the problem when I'm trying to use the withdraw function.

**This is my smart contract: **

```
contract MyContract{
    
    //Model of PPE
  struct Center{
    uint id;
    string name;
    uint ppeCount;
    address receiver;
  }
  mapping(uint => Center) private centers;
  
  address A1 = 0xB2F508Bf8E4A177934C8945B0D219601a5728c4B;
  address B1 = 0xDB9a942bd4B79c6203206779e7ffc7aF5d237180 ;

  
  //constructor
  constructor() public{
    addCenter('Health Ministry',A1);
    addCenter('Division',B1);
    
  }
//add center
  function addCenter(string memory _name, address _receiver) private {
    centerCount++;
    centers[centerCount] = Center(centerCount, _name, 0, _receiver);
  }
  
  function distribution(uint _centerId,  uint _amount) payable public{
      
      
      require(_centerId >0 && _centerId <= centerCount);

      if(_amount<100){
        revert('Sorry you have to send at least 100 ppe');
      }

      centers[_centerId].ppeCount+=_amount;
      
      if(_centerId == 1){
        balance+=_amount;
        bonus+=100;
        _view[_centerId] = PublicView(_centerId, 'Health Ministry', balance);
        
      }
      if(_centerId == 2){
        baln+=_amount;
        bonus+=100;
         _view[_centerId] = PublicView(_centerId, 'Division', baln);


      }
  }
function withdraw(uint _id, address yourAddress, uint _amount) public{
        secretAddress = msg.sender;
        
        if(secretAddress != yourAddress){
            revert("You don't have that right to withdraw even 1 ppe!");
        }
      
        
        if(_id == 1 && yourAddress == A1 &&_amount <= balance){
            balance -= _amount;
            centers[_id] = Center(_id, 'Health Ministry', balance, yourAddress);
            _view[_id] = PublicView(_id,'Health Ministry', balance);
            
        }
        else if(_id == 2 && yourAddress == B1 && _amount <= baln){
            baln -= _amount;
            centers[_id] = Center(_id, 'Authorized Hospital', baln, yourAddress);
             _view[_id] = PublicView(_id,'Division', baln);

            
        }
        else{
            revert("Id is not valid! ");
        }
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```
    //display centers update    
    contract.methods.getInfo(1).call().then(function(view){

        var id = view[0];
        var name = view[1];
        var ppeCount = view[2];
        
        var template = "<tr><th>" + id + "</th><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + ppeCount + "</td></tr>"
        //document.getElementById('distributionResult').innerHTML = template;
        document.getElementById('distributionResults').innerHTML = template;
          
        });
      

    //withdraw
    function withdraw(){
        var id = $('#yourId');
        var key = $('#privateKey');
        var amount = $('#amount');

       contract.methods.withdraw(id,key,amount).send({from: account}).then(function(result){
          console.log(result);
          location.reload();
       });
    }
```

**ejs file**

```
<div class="container">
          <img src="../public/img/blockchain-logo.jpg" width="300px" style="margin-top: -3rem;">
          <h3>Blockchain Based Center-Ganache Network</h3>
          <hr/>
          <br/>
            <div id="content">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Your ID</th>
                      <th scope="col">Your Center</th>
                      <th scope="col">Accepted PPE</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="distributionResults">
                  </tbody>
                </table>
            <hr/>
        <form>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="yourId">Enter your valid id</label>
                <input type = "number" class = "form-control" id="yourId">
                
                <label for="privateKey">Your private key</label>
                <input type="text"  class = "form-control" id="privateKey">
                
                <label for="amount">Enter Amount</label>
                <input class="form-control" id= "amount" type = number placeholder="Not less/ greater than your balance">
              </div>
              
              <a href="#" onclick="withdraw()" class="btn btn-info">withdraw</a>
              
              <hr />
            <p id="accountAddress" class="text-center">Your account: </p>
        </form>
        </div>
       </div>
```

**NOTE:** By doing this I'm getting error.which is :-

```
Uncaught Error: invalid address (argument="address", value={"0":{},"length":1}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.0.2) (argument="yourAddress", value={"0":{},"length":1}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.0-beta.153)
```

Comment: Function `withdraw` takes an `address` (160 bits) as the second input parameter, while you seem to be passing it a private key (256 bits).

Comment: In addition to that, at the beginning of this function, each one of `secretAddress = msg.sender;` and `if(secretAddress != yourAddress)` independently implies very little understanding of how contracts work, so I suggest you start with learning a bit about that (because solving this specific problem is not going to get you much further).

Comment: okay I understand. Actually it was my mistake. I forgot to put ```var id = $('#yourId').val()``` on main.js. Now it's working. @goodvibration